# Why do I keep getting this error when I try and run rake db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, dbmigrate, ancestry

```
==  AddAncestryToMessages: migrating ==========================================
-- add_column(:messages, :ancestry, :string)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: messages: ALTER TABLE "messages" ADD "ancestry" varchar(255)
```

so my application has messages that you can post (kind of like twitter) and Im adding replies, and I am using the ancestry gem to do so.

my code in my `schema.rb` file ( I think this is the file it uses to create tables every time you run rake db:migrate. but I could be wrong (This could be the problem!)

```
  create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "ancestry"
  end

  add_index "messages", ["user_id", "created_at", "ancestry"], :name =>   "index_messages_on_user_id_and_created_at_and_ancestry"
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, now I see: you added your code to the `schema.rb` but you had to use migrations. Remove your manually added code from `schema.rb` and run:

```
rails g migration CreateMessages
```

You'll get the file db/migrate/[timestamp]_create_messages.rb. Fill its `change` method with your code and then run (it should be created for you, but empty. For old versions it is named `up`):

```
rake db:migrate
```

This command will change your `schema.rb` by itself. **Don't change it manually!** (at lest till you become a mature Rails-programmer).

Comment: hmm that didnt work for me. I took out the t.string   "ancestry" and the "ancestry" from the add_index method therefore changing it back to its original state. then I ran rails g migration CreateMessages and it created the rb file for me. Then I copied and pasted all my code above into up. Is this all correct?

Comment: Wait a minute. *Changing it back to its original state* -- what did you mean? You already have table and just want to add index to it? If all you need is to add an index to the table you have then your `up`/`change` method should contain ONLY `add_index ....`. Also if you have `up` method then fill the `down` method with `remove_index, :name => "..."`.

Comment: @user1123905, almost correct.  In the up of the new rb file, you should call add_column and add_index, since as jdoe noted, you already have the table.